# Python itertools multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, permutation, product, python-itertools

I'm creating huge array of permutations with replacement (product) and it demands so much time for computation. Let's use simple function like this one:

```
def permutations(li):
    return [p for p in itertools.product(li, repeat=20)]

permutation(range(11))
```

I'm simply not sure how to split this function into multiple processes (using "Pool" class or similar). I have never used multiprocessing in Python and I'd like to ask for help.

Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module?

Comment: This is not so easy. You'll have to split this job in chunks or make each thread (or process) generate its own permutations

Comment: Maybe you'd like to try `cartesian` (`from sklearn.utils.extmath import cartesian`). It will give you more speed up than, for example mutiprocessing on 4 cores.

Comment: Why do you need them all in a `list`? You can `yield` one value at a time.

Comment: @Peter: That's what `itertools.product()` _does_ — so there's no need to `yield` anything, it's baked-in...but I agree about questioning why it has to be stored in a list.

Comment: Your code is attempting to generate a list with `11**20` elements. That's too large for any normal computer to handle. Even if your machine could generate a billion permutations a second, it would still take over 21318 years to enumerate them all.

Comment: @Peter A logical answer would be that one is trying to apply a function to those permutations; if you want to do it in parallel, you could partition that list and spawn a process to handle each partition separately. I agree that this approach is not the best, especially if the size of the list is 11**20. An approach in which one could iterate on partitions of the list without storing the list would be great.

Comment: @unutbu: ...much less process the 672,749,994,932,560,009,201 elements of the list.

Comment: Hi all. Thank you so much for the answers. I tried cartesian (from sklearn.utils.extmath. It didn't work also. Not to mention I have event larger set of permutations. So the new question is: What do you usually use in this kind of situations? Spark, MapReduce, something else..? Please someone point me into right direction and I will start digging into this... Thanks once again!

Comment: I would say look for greedy approximation of your task first before going distributed. General rules of thumb is avoid iteration on exponentially growing arrays / searching through exponentially growing spaces. @chapelo "Exp / poly" is still "Exp" for large N, no matter how many nodes you have.

Answer (score 5):

Too big divided by 4 is still Too big. Heed unutbu's comment: It would take forever divided by 4 doing it with multiprocessing.

However, here is a working example of just 3**2, assuming that you will do something useful in `your_process`:

```
import itertools
import multiprocessing

def your_process(perm):
    # this is where you process each permutation
    # currently it just prints the permutation.
    print(perm)

def permutations(li):
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as workers:
        workers.map(your_process, itertools.product(li, repeat=2))

permutations(range(3))
```

But if you really have >11**>20 permutations, consider using something like distributed computing or BOINC, or perhaps re-think your algorithm.

Comment: echo "Too big divided by 4 is still Too big". Nailed it